# Cached content for image element kept in browser after being removed and added again

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome

We are developing a web app where the interface uses AJAX/Javascript entirely.

There are certain dynamic images with cache expiration times of access + 15 minutes. So, when the images are accessed normally they are cached for 15 minutes and then after this time the browser will fetch a new version, caching again for 15 minutes and so on.

The issue is that in this AJAX setup, even when image elements are removed and then added, the newly added image element (which could be over 15 minutes later, when the browser would normally fetch the new image version) does not contain the new content. i.e. once the image is loaded in once, even after the element is removed, if this element is re-added at any other stage without the page being changed, only the originally loaded version will display.

So far this issue is with Chrome, I've not tested other browsers yet. The image appears to sort of be held in "memory" even when the image element is removed, the image shows under "resources" in Chrome developer tools - again, this is long after the image element specifying this image source has been removed.

What can I do about this? The only solution so far is to change the image filename on subsequent loads (the old query string trick perhaps). The issue here is that these images then stack up the in the "resources" tab of developer tools, as though they're being held open, despite the image elements being removed.

Hope this made sense. Any thoughts? I really just want Chrome (and maybe other browsers that have this issue) to load the image properly regardless of the source on new image elements. That is.. the route of check cache, if expired fetch from server and cache again.

Cheers

Comment: Firefox doesn't appear to have this issue :(

Comment: Other people have problems SIMILAR to mine (though I'd say mine is more like a browser bug). See http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=580a520136f53787&hl=en - I'm going to search a bit harder now than I've seen a bit of light, previously I couldn't find anybody with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've solved this is to append a random query string on to the path of the image. For example:

```
<img src="myimage.gif">
```

becomes

```
<img src="myimage.gif?a=randomnumber">
```

The random number will **force** the browser to grab the newest version.

Comment: Cheers and yeah, I mentioned this one in the question (though in our case the number would only change every 15 minutes to save extra loading). It just doesn't seem like something we should have to do. This is what the cache expiration times are for. In addition to this we have the worry that these image files then stack up further in the "resources" tab of Chrome developer tools, making us think that the browser is holding these images ready to use despite the elements being long removed.

Comment: We all know that Chrome caches the HELL out of stuff. If you're sure that the correct expires headers are being sent (maybe check the NET panel in firebug), and Chrome is still caching them longer than it should, the only way to ensure it loads the images afresh is to change the URL.

Comment: It is following the cache if pages are loaded separately, for example if I reload the actual page in the browser after 15 mins, the right images are shown for that period because the browser is no longer trapping the original image files for that page !!